# Mango tree not bearing any fruits after cyclone

Tags: fruits, damage, wind-damage

We have a relatively young (<15 years) mango tree in my hometown and it has beared fruits for more than 5 years. However two years back there was a cyclone(also known as hurricane/typhoon depending on the region). Although the tree didn't suffer any visible damage, it didn't bear any fruit last year or this year. It didn't flower either.

What should we do?